# How to correctly set up a RecyclerView with Fragments as children

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to use `Fragments` as my `RecyclerView` children to no avail.

What I have I'm trying to do is load some `ArrayList` of custom `POJO` classes from my `Firebase Database` and each of those items has content to be displayed as the header and the main content.

For that I have created a **Foldable layout** where the user first sees the header layout and on clicking the desired child in the layout,they are presented with the main content.

The **Header layout** is a simple `ConstraintLayout` so no problem in binding data to views. But my **Content layout** is a `ViewPager` coupled with `TabLayout` to host three `Fragments` whose data comes from the `ArrayList` fetched from `Firebase`.

My problem comes in where only the first child's `Fragments` show data in the `onClick` event but the rest don't.

This is my `RecyclerView Adapter`:

```
public class OrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.viewHolder> {

public static boolean canScroll;
public static String image;
public static String message;
private static boolean isUser;
private static int scrollTo;
private static List<Order> beanOrders;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public OrdersAdapter(List<Order> beanOrders, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    OrdersAdapter.beanOrders = beanOrders;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new viewHolder(new FoldableLayout(parent.getContext()));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewHolder holder, int i) {
    ArrayList<String> location = beanOrders.get(i).getLocation();
    String county = location.get(0);
    String consti = location.get(1);
    String ward = location.get(2);
    String estate = location.get(3);
    String apartm = location.get(4);

    if (beanOrders.get(i).isTaken()) {
        holder.flHolder.setBackground(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vector_free));
    } else if (beanOrders.get(i).isDelivered()) {
        holder.flHolder.setBackground(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vector_delid));
    }

    holder.tvWorth.setText(String.format("Ksh %s", beanOrders.get(i).getsWorth()));
    holder.tvNumber.setText(beanOrders.get(i).getsPhone());
    holder.tvUserName.setText(beanOrders.get(i).getsName());
    holder.tvCouConWard.setText(String.format("%s , %s , %s", county, consti, ward));
    holder.tvEstApart.setText(String.format("%s , %s", estate, apartm));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != beanOrders ? beanOrders.size() : 0);
}

private void setUpData(viewHolder holder, String image, String message) {
    setUpViewPager(holder.vpAdmin, image, message, fragmentManager);
    holder.tbAdmin.setupWithViewPager(holder.vpAdmin);
    holder.vpAdmin.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            isUser = i == 2;
            if (i == 2) {
                holder.fabClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_eraser);
            } else holder.fabClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_fold);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
}

private void setUpViewPager(HViewPager viewPager, String image, String message, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    FragmentsAdapter fragmentsAdapter = new FragmentsAdapter(fragmentManager);

    Image fragmentImage = Image.newInstance(image);
    Message fragmentMessage = Message.newInstance(message);

    fragmentsAdapter.addFragment(new Image(), "Image");
    fragmentsAdapter.addFragment(new Message(), "Confirmation");
    fragmentsAdapter.addFragment(new Delivery(), "Delivery");

    viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentsAdapter);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
}

class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    FoldableLayout flAdmin;
    @BindView(R.id.tbAdmin)
    TabLayout tbAdmin;
    @BindView(R.id.vpAdmin)
    HViewPager vpAdmin;
    @BindView(R.id.fabClose)
    FloatingActionButton fabClose;
    @BindView(R.id.tvUserName)
    AppCompatTextView tvUserName;
    @BindView(R.id.tvNumber)
    AppCompatTextView tvNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.tvWorth)
    AppCompatTextView tvWorth;
    @BindView(R.id.tvCouConWard)
    AppCompatTextView tvCouConWard;
    @BindView(R.id.tvEstApart)
    AppCompatTextView tvEstApart;
    @BindView(R.id.tvLoyalty)
    AppCompatTextView tvLoyalty;
    @BindView(R.id.tvPoints)
    AppCompatTextView tvPoints;
    @BindView(R.id.flHolder)
    FrameLayout flHolder;

    viewHolder(FoldableLayout foldableLayout) {
        super(foldableLayout);
        flAdmin = foldableLayout;
        foldableLayout.setupViews(R.layout.layout_c_header, R.layout.layout_c_content, R.dimen.cover_height, itemView.getContext());
        ButterKnife.bind(this, foldableLayout);

        vpAdmin.setPagingEnabled(false);

        canScroll = true;

        fabClose.setOnClickListener(this);

        flAdmin.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            image = beanOrders.get(getLayoutPosition()).getsImage();
            message = beanOrders.get(getLayoutPosition()).getsMessage();

            setUpData(this, image, message);
            tbAdmin.setupWithViewPager(vpAdmin);

            //Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), beanOrders.get(getLayoutPosition()).getsMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> canScroll = false, 1000);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ConstHelper.START_SCROLL);
            intent.putExtra(ConstHelper.SMOOTH_SCROLL, true);
            intent.putExtra(ConstHelper.SCROLL_TO, getLayoutPosition());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(itemView.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

            if (flAdmin.isFolded()) {
                flAdmin.unfoldWithAnimation();
            } else {
                flAdmin.foldWithAnimation();
            }
        });

        flAdmin.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
            canScroll = true;
            return true;
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        canScroll = true;
        if (isUser) {
            canScroll = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(ConstHelper.SIGNATURE_CALL);
            intent.putExtra(ConstHelper.CLEAR_CUSTOMER, true);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(viewHolder.this.itemView.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        } else {
            if (!flAdmin.isFolded()) {
                flAdmin.foldWithAnimation();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        //TODO send report that order has been received

        return true;
    }
}}
```

The fragments are simple and two follow this pattern:

```
public class Message extends Fragment {
@BindView(R.id.tvConfirmation)
AppCompatTextView tvConfirmation;
Unbinder unbinder;

public Message() {
}

public static Message newInstance(String message) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Message", message);

    Message fragmentMessage = new Message();
    fragmentMessage.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragmentMessage;
}

private void readBundle(Bundle bundle) {
    if (bundle != null) {
        //message = bundle.getString("Message");
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_f_message, container, false);

    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    tvConfirmation.setText(OrdersAdapter.message);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), OrdersAdapter.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //readBundle(getArguments());
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}}
```

The other one just loads an image and the last is not linked to the data I'm fetching.

**What I've tried**

1. Using `Bundles` to deliver the data to the `Fragment`.
2. Switching where I load my `Fragments` from `ViewHolder` class to `onBindViewHolder` method.

The first seems to work from my debugging but still the issue prevails no matter what.

This is an image of the above situation:
[image: Image here]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by removing all the ```static``` qualifiers from the Adapter's variables. After that, seeing what you want to accomplish, I strongly suggest moving away from the complexity of Fragment to simple Views and ViewHolders. Finally make sure you notify the adapter of any changes.

Comment: @iFanie thanks for the response but I don't see any other way to accomplish what I want without the Fragments.Also the adapter is notified but via the class from where I have bound it to the RecyclerView

Comment: As you wish, then remove all static qualifiers because they should not be there. You want every adapter instance to have it's own set of data and flags.

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo getting and displaying the data is not an issue.But thanks for the suggestion.My problem is using Fragments as children in my Recyclerview

Comment: @iFanie thanks for the suggestion I actually made it work by switching the view to simpler ones.Maybe you can add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @The-Kamble i did, thanks for this. Did you also remove the static variables?

Comment: No the static variables are mandatory.I know it is not a good design pattern but for now itll do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by removing all the `static` qualifiers from the Adapter's variables. After that, seeing what you want to accomplish, I strongly suggest moving away from the complexity of Fragment to simple Views and ViewHolders. Finally, make sure you `notify` the adapter of any changes.